# How to fix homebrew error: "invalid active developer path" after upgrade to OS X El Capitan?

Tags: homebrew, macos

I get this error when I run `brew update`:

```
$ brew update
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Run the following commands to fix the above error

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

I found the answer on https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23500

I also had to do this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Because of some permission issues. However, do this only if you have to.

Comment: I had to add `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` instead of just `sudo xcode-select -switch /` but otherwise this worked great. No need for me to chown the files though.

Comment: And don't forget to restart terminal after any new installs..

Answer (score 55):

Only the following command should resolve the issue if you are the admin on the machine.

```
xcode-select --install
```

The following article helped me solve the issue

http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/

Comment: This is better than the [selected answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209624/how-to-fix-homebrew-error-invalid-active-developer-path-after-upgrade-to-os-x/209625#209625) because it simpler and doesn't use `sudo`. It worked after my Catalina upgrade. I didn't even need to restart Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after updating to Catalina 10.15 here is what I found:

The error is alerting you that you need to (re) install X-code command-line tools.

run

```
xcode-select --install
```

after this, run

```
brew outdated
```

then

```
brew upgrade
```

While Homebrew automatically uninstalls old versions of formulas every 30 days you can still run the following to get ride of any unneeded stuff.

```
brew cleanup -n
```

and

```
brew cleanup
```

To learn more about homebrew check out the documentation on https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ

Comment: Actually, that's not what the error message was saying, `xcrun` is no longer at that path. It was a bug/incompatibility issue with homebrew that was fixed years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that!

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem after updating macOS to Mojave (maybe updating the OS can causes this).

To fix it, I simply installed `Xcode` from the App Store instead of doing the command line stuff.

Answer (score 2):

@Ranjith Ramachandra answer but I was able to get everything to work by only running the install command with sudo so if you’ve got modified permissions, forcing root may be needed

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: That *might* because your path was correct, but the command line tools were outdated.  Nice that you got it done! But did you really need to use `sudo`?

Comment: Needing sudo is a sign that you have a non-standard setup. It may not be wrong for you, but will confuse others and doesn’t follow the out of the box macos and brew.sh idiom. I would run `brew doctor` and fix any permissions issues rather than force things with sudo here. Also, what was correct when this was asked may have changed so I won’t -1 this even though it doesn’t hold for macOS Catalina.